# Run a script which is in a django app under management folder in command folder

Tags: python, django

I have a django project and inside I have an app. Inside this app I created a management folder, inside this one I create a commands folder, and inside the last one I put my script with the **init**.py file too. My question is how I can run the script, because if I'm in the django project folder (where is manage.py file) and I execute the line:

```
python manage.py myscript.py
```

the terminal is displaying this:

```
Unknown command: 'myscript.py'
```

Comment: You don't need the .py extension - e.g python manage.py my_script Both management and commands folders need a init file in them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `python manage.py myscript`, and if everything else is correct it will work.

Note that management command is not just a python script. It must implement `class Command` inside. ([Tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/custom-management-commands/))